# "Invalid declaration method" in java

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Bugs{
   private String bugType;
   private int legs;
   private int arms;
   private String nativeTo;

   public bug(String bt, int l, int a, String nt){
      bt=bugType;
      l=legs;
      a=arms;
      nt=nativeTo;
   }
}
```

Why do I keep getting a "invalid declaration method" here? It keeps saying a return method is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor must be named the same as your class. Bugs, not bug. You are basically declaring a method without return type what is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

The method that you want here is a special one called *constructor*. Constructors are used when you create new objects. In contrast to regular methods they don't have a declared return type.

You should change the line

```
public bug(String bt, int l, int a, String nt){
```

to

```
public Bugs(String bt, int l, int a, String nt){
```

it has to match the name of the class exactly.

You can read more about constructors here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 1):

change `public bug` to `public Bugs` if you want to make it a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). Otherwise if it is a method add a `return` statement before the last `}` of the method and also add a return type in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Change `public bug` to `public Bugs`. This is because it is a constructor that must be the same as the class name.